# Can I record contributions and pledge payments in a "Batch Data Entry" of type pledge payment?

Tags: civicontribute, civipledge

When using a data entry batch of type "Pledge Payment" can I record stand-alone contributions as well as pledge payments in the same batch?

(It seemed like I could do this in 4.6.0, but its not working in 4.6.3. In 4.6.3 I get the following message for contacts with no pledge selected: "Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
You can not record two payments for the same pledge in a single batch." )

Comment: The JIRA 
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15701
 describes that recording pledge payments and contributions in the same batch should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

While in 4.7.7 (sorry, don't have a 4.6.3 environment to test), it is technically possible to record stand-alone contributions in a batch created for pledge payments by leaving the "Open Pledges (Due Date - Amount)" field blank and selecting the desired financial type, in a recent session at CiviCON 2016, Joe Murray indicated that best practice would be to record each type of contribution with the batch entry category that it falls into (i.e. use contribution for stand-alone contributions and pledge payment for pledge payments), although I clearly see the convenience of being able to record multiple contribution types in a single batch entry.

Hope this helps,
Tamar